# Td operator with zero y-coordinate

Tags: pdf

In the text object (ctm: [0.0 -1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]):

```
BT...
.
-7.1439 -1.2 TD
   // sets tm to [0.0 9.0 -9.0 0.0 143.333 509.541]
   // &   tlm to [0.0 9.0 -9.0 0.0 143.333 509.541]
.1903 Tw
[(d)-8(a)-3.1(ri)8.8(n e)-5.9(n).3(t)-11.2(h)-4.5(al)-6.9(t)-11.3(e)-5.9(n)-5.5(e)-5.9(n S)5.5(i)1.4(c)-6.8(h)-5.5(e)-7.8(r)-5.2( )]TJ
   // tm before  [0.0 9.0 -9.0 0.0 143.333 655.732]
10.9872 0 TD
   // tm after   [0.0 9.0 -9.0 0.0 143.333 608.426]
   // tlm after  [0.0 9.0 -9.0 0.0 143.333 608.426]
-.0042 Tc
.1946 Tw
[(h)-9.8(e)-3.1(it)-15.7(s)-6.3(h)6.1(in)9(wei)5.3(s)-11.8(e a)-7.4(b)-4.2( S)-17.8(e)-3.1(it)-15.6(e 4.)]TJ
.
...ET
```

'10.9872 0 TD' sets the textmatrix back to the start of the line (+ 10.9872 units), resulting in a messed up glyph/character order:

- "darin enthaltenen Sheiticshheinr weise ab Seite 4." instead of
- "darin enthaltenen Sicher heitshinweise ab Seite 4."

Given that my other calculations are correct (not sure about that), what else could I've been missing?

- link to [pdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g89v0ant7g7ec35/iTeufel-Air-Update_DE_web.pdf?dl=1), first page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually calculated the text matrix changes. Just like you I got to a

```
[0.0 9.0 -9.0 0.0 143.3332 509.5413]
```

before the first **TJ** instruction, but I got a different matrix after the **TJ** instruction itself:

- The glyph widths add up to 10835.
- The numeric **TJ** parameter array values add up to -77.5.
- There are 25 glyphs, 3 spaces among them.
- Thus, the combined horizontal displacement is

  ```
  (10835 + 77.5) / 1000 + 25*.0001 + 3*.1903 = 10.9125 + .0025 + .5709 = 11.4859
  ```

Applying this displacement to the text matrix, one gets

```
[0.0 9.0 -9.0 0.0 143.3332 612.9144]
```

which corresponds quite neatly to the

```
[0.0 9.0 -9.0 0.0 143.333 608.426]
```

(which you calculated as text matrix after the following **TD** instruction) plus the apparently unwanted space character.

Thus, you should check your code for determining the horizontal displacement of a **TJ** instruction and for applying it to the text matrix.

Comment: Well, I bluntly added wordspace to every glyph, not only spaces, according to "((w0 -Tj/1000) x Tfs + Tc + Tw) x Th". This reference makes me mad, "if applicable". Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: *grin* Yeah, sometimes the PDF specification is less than self-explanatory. By the way, the exact requirement is: **Word spacing shall be applied to every occurrence of the single-byte character code 32 in a string when using a simple font or a composite font that defines code 32 as a single-byte code. It shall not apply to occurrences of the byte value 32 in multiple-byte codes.**